# Is the relation of belonging antisymmetric?

Tags: set-theory

In set theory (the usual ZFC axioms), can I say that the relation of belonging ($\in$)is antisymmetric? I guess so since I think this is vacuously true due to regularity.

Comment: In fact, $\in$ is asymmetric: with the axiom of regularity, no set could ever be a member of itself.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks, that answers my question.